# how to add facility like google docs has in my project

Tags: java, maven, google-docs

I want to create maven project like compare to office docs with it syntax. So I think to download Google docs API.

But I didn't find any link to download it. so any API that do this or download link and sample for achieve it using Google docs or other.

Answer (score 0):

You can't download Google docs the same way you download an Office file. Even the Google docs inside of the Google Drive are actually just links.

What you have to do instead is learn how to interface with the API. This will allow you to manipulate Google docs.

https://developers.google.com/drive/

Comment: Thanks for answering but I already read that and I am not understanding from this I need some example to implement this so will u have any example or sample for implement drive in web project(Maven).

Comment: another api i found is ZOHO remote api. if u know anything about this how to implement zoho in maven project with sample...

Comment: Hi Wala, here's a series of videos explaining how to use the API. http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/discover-drive/intro

Comment: ZOHO is the same as Google. Manipulate the docs via their APIs as well. Same with Box, Dropbox, ...